# How to keep symbol bindings local to a Notebook section?

Tags: notebooks, scoping, wolfram-cloud, contexts

I'm using the Notebook on Wolfram-Cloud as a ... well ... notebook to keep notes about the topic I'm studying and to answer exercises. I usually keep one notebook file per chapter, with course notes on the top, and exercises solution on the bottom (see the screen capture below)

[image: Notebok screen capture]

This sometimes cause me troubles when a symbol is bound to some value in one exercise, then the same symbol name is re-used in a different exercise. I could [`Clear`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html?q=Clear) all symbols used at the start of each exercise section. But it seems quite cumbersome.

**What are the best practices/solutions to ensure definitions and symbol bindings to stay local to a given section?**

More formally, I was looking for a way to keep bindings [lexically scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1047491/2363712) to  sections (and its subsections)

---

I tried [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) but it does not allow the module content to be broken in different notebook parts:
[image]

Comment: Use a cell context that is specific to each cell group?

Comment: Thanks @Mike. Well, I never heard about "cell context" nor "cell groups". You gave me new search terms to explore the Wolfram Langage documentation!

Comment: @Mike indeed, it looks promising. But at first sight, the doc is sparse, to say the least: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellContext.html

Answer (score 5):

You could try implementing one of these options -- whatever works best for you:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> CellGroup]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Cell]
```

other possibilities, less likely based on your requirements:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Style]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mike. I saw something like that while searching for a solution. But I didn't manage to group cells, nor use stylesheets from Wolfram Cloud. All the docs seem to refer to the Desktop Notebook. Or did I missed something?

Comment: You can group cells by making sections, subsections etc

Comment: Ah, OK. I though that was a different concept.

Comment: Actually @Mike, I was unable to make that work. Probably by my lack of understanding _where_ I'm supposed to change the `CellContext`. Since this is somewhat at the margin of my initial question, I asked a [new question for that specific issue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211257/what-is-the-proper-way-of-setting-cellcontext-cellgroup-in-the-wolfram-clo).

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find how to use CellContext and cell groups in the Wolfram Cloud Notebook. As a workaround, I create a new context for each exercise using [`Begin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Begin.html) and [`End`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/End.html):

> ### Ex 3.4
>
> ```
>  Begin["Ex3x4`"]
> ```
>
> *<<< mix of text cells and computation here >>>*
>
> ```
>  While[$Context != "Global`", End[]]
> ```

I wrap the `End[]` call in a [`While`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While.html?q=While) loop to ensure I restore the Global context, since, in Notebook interactive usage, the cell containing `Begin` may end-up being evaluated more than one.

[image]