# Can I repeat variables in different sections of a notebook without affecting each other?

Tags: notebooks

Suppose I have a section in a notebook and I do some manipulation on data and use some variables in that section. Can I use the same variables in a different section of the notebook to do manipulation on different set of data such that when I access the first section of notebook all the calculation remain intact?

Comment: Like in docs and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211221/5478?

Comment: If you do nothing, then variables are global so that x in one place is the same as x in any other place. Look at Block for local scoping of variables. Or you can make individual notebooks a local environment.

Comment: Also look at `Module`

Comment: Look also at: "tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings#27982" in the help